# how can I compute taxes using Roomle Price Service?

Tags: roomle

I would like to have taxes separated from the main price and have a label in the Part List indicating how much they are. Is it possible to compute the taxes if I am using Roomle Price Service?

I tried to do it with JavaScript and used `configurator.ui.setPrice('€', priceSum + taxes)`, but every time I click on the Part List, the price reverts to the old one without taxes.

Answer (score 0):

The prices in the `Part List` are directly fetched from the `csv` file uploaded to Roomle Admin, see https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/200_130_pricing.html#price-service

The `setPrice` API is meant to be used when calculating your prices without using the price service.